# How to only trim the last new line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> 'test string\n\n\n'.rstrip('\n')
'test string'
```

The above command trims all the newlines at the end. Is there a succinct way to just remove the last newline?

Comment: [`removesuffix('\n')`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/) on Python 3.9 or later

Answer (score 4):

[`removesuffix('\n')`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/) on Python 3.9 or later.

In earlier versions:

```
if string.endswith('\n'):
    string = string[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use regex for this problem. You can use split and join to solve this.

```
#readable
a = string_text.split('\n')
result = ('\n').join(a[:-1])

#quick
result = ('\n').join(string_text.split('\n')[:-1]
```